# Magento - Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists

Tags: php, mysql, magento, registry, magento-1.6

I'm migrating a magento 1.6.1 installation on my staging server, but I'm still getting the error `Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists`.

I migrated the db and the whole source code. Then I changed `local.xml` database settings.

I already ran `rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*` and restarted Apache2 but can't get it working.

What should I do?

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano whoops, I forgot to put it inside the description. I edited the post. The error is the same you see in the title `Mage registry key "_resource_helper/core" already exists`.

Comment: i think this link is one of best solution. [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/234325/) and [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_1.5_to_1.6_upgrade)

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano Thanks! I've already found the 2nd link but also clearing the session and cache folders it doesn't work. Actually I got it working by commenting out the line that's raising the exception, but soon I'll need to migrate the production website to a dedicated VPS, and I'm scared I'll get again this same error :-s

Comment: enjoy your problem. no problem no experience :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeeep! I finally got it working. The issue here was that performing the migration I also changed the `<model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>` value.

This was causing the exception... Now that I restored the default value it's all working without hacking the normal behaviour :-)

Comment: Hi, i have this same problem, can you complete your post on what did you do to get it fixed?

Comment: Had the same problem. For some reason it said just mysql in there and the right one was mysql4. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: For informations, here there is a 1.9.2.1 local.xml.template : https://gist.github.com/Nolwennig/210440a07a4b48feca0c#file-xml

Comment: <model> has to  be added to app/etc/local.xml in the node config->global->resources->default_setup->connection

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. For me, this fixed it:

```
rm -rf /tmp/magento/var/cache/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add this on local.xml:

```
<model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
```

IF you already did this and error persist, you need clear your cache. Inside of your magento folder:

```
rm -rf var/cache/
```

or remove manually.
;)